# rm -f and makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, vxworks

One of the many makefiles in my project shows errors in the error console when there are no files to delete even though the -f flag is being used. Here's the offending line in the makefile

`-rm -f *.o`

If I remove the dash at the beginning of the line, it stops dead in its tracks - so I know that this is the line that's generating the error.

This is a big project with a dozen or so makefiles. What I don't understand is that some of the others don't have this problem.

This is the embedded programming world - I'm using WindRiver 2.6 (so the rm utility is "rm.EXE", though it seems to have the usual options).

Does anyone know why an "rm -f" call would still generate an error if there's nothing to delete?

Comment: C:\WindRiver22\workbench-2.6\x86-win32\bin\rm.EXE: cannot remove `*.sm': Invalid argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the WindRiver tools, but here's an educated guess based on the behavior of typical Unix shells and `make` tools.

When you run `rm -f *.o`, the following happens:

- the shell tries to expand `*.o`, leaving it as is if there are no files matching it (try issuing `echo *.o` in a dir containing no such files, and one with such files)
- the result of the expansion is passed to `rm`, so if there are no matching files, `rm` is called with the literal string `*.o` as its argument
- `rm` interprets as arguments as path names, without expanding patterns (because that's the shell's job); the `-f` shuts it up if a file cannot be found

From the error message, it looks like your `rm` is broken in that it still complains when no file called `*.o` can be found. You can work around this by first checking whether any file matches the pattern. I must admit that I don't know how to do that in your environment.

Comment: This sounds very reasonable. How would you normally check to see if the files exist first? I've never done that it a makefile...

Comment: I think I found it: rm -f $(wildcard *.sm) ... that worked... when you said that it resolved to a literal "*.o" I was able to (finally!) get it working... it still prints "rm -f" but there's no error :) Thanks!

Comment: if you add a @ in front of the command the command line executed will not be printed out

Answer (score 2):

In Windows environment it can't expand "*.o" and sends it as is to `rm` command, in fact `rm.exe` from `cygwin` for example, which then fails with error exit code. It is difficult to see while running `rm.exe` from Windows's `cmd` command prompt as it's appearing to complete OK with the same arguments.

The solution is to use `$(wildcard *.o)` in makefile. It's important to have "*", as otherwise nothing will be expanded even if file exists.

As a result, the line in make file will look similar to this:

```
rm -f $(wildcard *.o) $(wildcard *.elf) $(wildcard *.lst) $(wildcard *.map) $(wildcard *.sym) $(wildcard *.lss) $(wildcard *.eep) $(wildcard *.srec) $(wildcard *.bin) $(wildcard *.hex) $(wildcard *.tmp.sh)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows use `del` command to remove files in `Makefile`

```
clean:
    del *.o *.exe
```